# OK to comment I'm livestreaming an attempt to answer?

Tags: support, policy

EDIT: To clarify, I still post the answer on StackExchange when I'm done (I usually type out the answer while on stream). Currently, when I post an answer I've livestreamed, I include a link to the YouTube recording so people can see how I did it, but I wasn't sure if livestreaming would be more useful/permitted/etc.

I sometimes live stream my attempts to answer StackExchange questions, and was wondering if it was ok to add a comment to the question saying "I'm livestreaming my attempt to answer this at [URL]".

I realize there are lots of reasons re whether to stream at all, and I may ask them in a separate "*should* I livestream my attempts to answer", but, for now, I'm just asking if there's a StackExchange policy or general guidance on this issue

EDIT: Per the comments and for reference, here are recordings of some StackExchange-answering livestreams I've done. I normally do mention the recordings when answering the question, but, again, that's after the fact (some of the earlier streams have a few seconds cutoff right at the start):

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rxX9iwBJ1A
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZMizS9aw4M [bad audio first 3m]
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7ULekl7OrY
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BY5FEREv7Vw
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnqNH3HyQyg
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pbfRghlqIOs
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLrLjnYkIxU
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yPk7Jk1PAc
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NFSmmsvjUU
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERKeS8TRtQA
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nEc4xeqjScE
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tbr8j_ozO3w
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLU3Vc1F4To
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S93rPb5RMeI
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AYE7F8603s
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mw_19ZjPgzc
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIgmw86XTK8
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uq9BuHJ-6SY
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkAiwQOki18
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5nJojIRwPM

Comment: Pretty sure that's off-limits for multiple reasons: it's not good for posterity, it brings no real use to the user (some would easily argue that if they need to *livestream* an answer, the scope of the question is too big), and its value is dubious.

Comment: OP is being responsible and asking on meta before going ahead and commenting on questions and folks are down-voting the question? How else do you expect him to learn?

Comment: I edited to indicate that the answer would still be on StackExchange in the end.

Comment: Keep in mind that comments are only meant to ask for clarification or point out problems to a post. Announcing livestreams does not really fit with that goal. On the other hand I do like the idea. I can imagine you keep the livestream links in your about me but mention them when you leave comment if you have to ask for clarification. Clean up those comments once the issue is resolved and/or the livestream is finished.

Comment: @Script47 As is done on other meta sites, downvotes might be used here to as way of expressing disagreement with the notion. It's unfortunate that meta sites don't have separate ways for participants to express yay/nay from rating the quality/usefulness of questions. If points are a consideration, this distinction would be even more useful on meta.SE.

Comment: Personally, I don't see any downside to this, as you've clarified your intent to answer the question in written form on the site after the stream.  One caveat being that the livestream isn't also some promotion/marketing vehicle--and perhaps that's not a problem either as long as folks are made aware of it before joining the stream.  (Disclaimer: All of this is just my opinion, so I cannot provide the "official stance" that I assume you're seeking.)

Comment: Would it be possible to give an example of when this might be used?  (Hypothetical or not.)  So that we all have approximately the same mental picture.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I've now added several examples.

Comment: I think it would be useful for you to include a link alongside at least one of these videos to the answer it corresponds to.  I know I never follow links to YouTube unless I know something about what is at the other end.

Comment: @faintsignal maybe for `[feature-request]` but very rarely for `[support]` from what I've seen.

Comment: I don't see why folks are in such a tizzy. Think of the livestream as an alternative to "let's discuss this in chat". As the OP made clear in the first edit, it is not intended to replace the answer.  No one is compelled to participate if they do not so wish.

Comment: How does a livestream of the answer help to improve the question? A: it doesn't. Therefore, it shouldn't be placed in a comment. @faintsignal

Comment: @Nij *How* cannot be answered by yes or no. I'm not going to waste energy on those determined to be obtuse on the topic.

Comment: "Keep in mind that comments are only meant to ask for clarification or point out problems to a post." –– It is true that the current site rules say that that is the only allowed use of comments, but I have not seen any proof that that is the only useful way to use comments. And until I see that proof, e.g. in an experiment where on SE site changes their rules and after a certain time the usefulness of the comments is evaluated, I don't believe that this part of the site rules is sensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many procedures that can be better explained using a video, e.g. sports exercises, drawing, or repairing something. Since the purpose of these sites (from a user perspective) is to provide helpful answers, videos – either embedded or linked – can be valid contributions.

A livestream on the other hand is not an answer. It is an answer in progress. While there may be rare cases when watching an answer being made might be helpful (e.g. when the question is about the answering process), in most cases the raw, unfinished answer will be of less value than the final, edited one. A YouTube video allows me to stop the video while I follow the advice, or to jump to where the information is that I need. A livestream forces me to wait out its end and to watch parts of the answer that might be irrelevant to me.

## tl;dr

- Video? Yes.
- Livestream? Mostly no.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, partly because you are correct in saying you can't fast forward a live stream, but also because you can't "reverse" a live stream on the platform I use. In other words, if you arrive an hour into the stream, you can't skim or "watch at accelerated speed" the first hour of the stream to catch up. Based on these limitations, I agree that posting a live stream is nearly useless.

Answer (score 8):

You have not described the purpose of your livestream, and so I would interpret this as a form of advertising for it and as such I think that advertising should not be done.

By all means feel free to livestream but only advertise that you are doing that via other means such as Twitter.

Comment: What's the difference between a live stream link and a link pointing to a blog post written by the same user who commented it?

Comment: @Script47 probably no difference and I think both are temporary comments subject to deletion.

Answer (score -3):

> OK to comment I'm livestreaming an attempt to answer?

I was initially going to say no based on the reasons provided by Sébastien Renauld, but, after considering it further I guess it would be fine. My reasoning for this answer is that it would be akin to leaving any other off-site resource in the comments to help the OP of the question.

On the other hand, it might be seen as spam/shameless plugs so it might very likely be deleted depending on the mod that happens across it, but again, I'm sure people have linked their own off-site resources that weren't in the format of videos/streams without issue.

<strike><sub>Tangentially, using videos to answer a question definitely would not be ideal from the askers perspective.</sub></strike>

Comment: You shouldn't be leaving links in comments either. If you have material that answers the question, *go and answer the question*. Link-only answers are subject to deletion as VLQ for good reason, and trying them in comments is even worse for more reasons.

Comment: '*You shouldn't be leaving links in comments either. If you have material that answers the question, go and answer the question.*' - It is a well established practice that folks who don't have the time to answer leave comments to resources which might help the OP. Since when has that changed?  '*Link-only answers are subject to deletion as VLQ for good reason, and trying them in comments is even worse for more reasons.*' - @Nij that's just wrong. Link-only comments are far better than link only answers and actually, I'd like to hear the reasons why you think otherwise.

Comment: If you're answering the question, write an answer, and do it properly. If you "don't have the time" to do it properly, leave it until you do and for others to answer in the meantime. Junk comments not only can't be downvoted, but appear higher than answers, distracting people from where they should be going for information.

Comment: @Nij that might be your opinion and that's fine, but that isn't how it works in reality.

Comment: "How it works in reality" is what I've described. Your reality is clearly different, that said, you shouldn't be giving advice that is obviously not universally applicable nor appreciated by the majority.

Comment: @Nij I'm sorry what? Please, take a moment and look through questions and see how many highly up-voted comments point to off-site resources which aid users. What you are describing is NOT reality, rather, it's is probably how you'd like things to work, but it definitely is not reality.

Comment: @Nij https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17786/who-are-the-olympic-athletes-from-russia/17787#comment28156_17786 | https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17786/who-are-the-olympic-athletes-from-russia/17787#comment28156_17786 | https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14179/what-do-the-tiny-yellow-rc-cars-next-to-the-javelin-throwing-field-do/14180#comment21321_14180 | https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/are-there-any-sports-that-started-as-a-womens-sport/13402#comment25201_13396 [1/2]

Comment: The majority of sites I'm active on, links in comments are removed and the poster asked to write a proper answer. If you mean specifically Meta, well, using that as an example of the network is like using movies reviews as an example of blockbuster films.

Comment: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17636/what-does-the-superscript-used-in-tennis-scores-mean/17638#comment27973_17636 | @Nij Are just a few of the posts you've posted answers in and in the comments other users have off-site resources. Don't tell me what I'm saying is not reality when it quite literally is. [2/2]

Comment: So, comments that I've previously flagged for removal are evidence that they're not flagged for removal? Comments with a single vote are highly upvoted? Like I said, your reality is different from mine.

Comment: @Nij '*So, comments that I've previously flagged for removal are evidence that they're not flagged for removal?*' - You saying it doesn't happen and is not reality is what I've proving wrong. You've clearly misunderstood the chain of comments, do have reread, if you fancy. '*Comments with a single vote are highly upvoted?*' - No? Like I mentioned (again, it seems you missed it), I was simply outlining a reality, that folks do comment with off-site resources in the comments. '*Like I said, your reality is different from mine.*' - Fundamentally, I don't think you understand the word "reality".